# What is the difference between the document selector and window selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, window, document

I have the following JQuery function that takes user input and displays it on screen. When I select for both `$(document)` and `$(window)` the function works. What is the disadvantage to using either selector? Where can I read more on these selectors and their differences?

Thank you in advance.

```
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 13) {
          var id = $("input#example").val()
          console.log(id);
          $('#data').append(id);
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While using the `window` or `document` object in a [jQuery dom selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), most of the time you won't notice a difference between the two.

However, it's important to note that they are not the same object.

`window` - refers to the viewport. It's used as the main global object in JavaScript. 
`document` - a direct descendant of `window`; refers to the [root of the document tree](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-core.html#i-Document).

All DOM elements are a descendant of the `document`, which is a direct descendant of `window`.

Comment: No kidding, have any references?

Comment: It's not the same. $(window) refers to the viewport and $(document) to the entire site. For example, $(window).height() and $(document).height() will often return different results.

Comment: A good example is the native `resize` event, which you can only find on the `window` object.

Answer (score 24):

`$(window)` selector is for selecting the viewport

`$(document)` selector is for the entire document (that is, what's inside the `<html>` tag, even if it exapnds beyond the viewport).

Comment: Agree. IMO in this case it's more logical to use `$(window)` instead of `$(document)` as a keypress cannot technically happen outside the viewport.

Comment: What if the website uses frames?

Comment: in all honesty I haven't used frames since the year 2000 or maybe before that, way before jQuery was invented, But if I were to speculate, I'd say it's the same, the viewport framee of the document in contrast to the entire document.

Answer (score 2):

To answer this question let me begin with the definition of the DOM, what we commonly know as "`document`".

> The Document Object Model (DOM) is an application programming interface (API) for valid HTML and well-formed XML documents. It defines the logical structure of documents and the way a `document` is accessed and manipulated. In the DOM specification, the term "document" is used in the broad sense.

Now let me explain a little of what I found about `browsing context`s, as that is the relationship that a `Document` and a `Window` normally have—although it is important to mention that a `Document` may exist without a `browsing context`, but you should never see that with jquery.

A user interacts with the main view of the `Document`. A view is defined as the media that is being used to present the `Document` to the user agent—e.g. screen, print, speech. The main view is the default view and is represented by an `AbstractView` object that implements the `Window` interface.

And to put it really simple, `window` is the container and `document` is the content. But I do recommend to at least skim through the documentation of this to have a better understanding.

Sources:

- [W3C - What is the
  DOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-DOM/introduction.html),
- [W3C - Browsing
  contexts](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090423/browsers.html#windows)